# How to find X value for slope of zero from a natural cubic spline in RStudio

Tags: splines

I have a scatter plot that I've fitted with a natural cubic spline with 4 knots using ns(), pictured below:

[image]

I would like to find the value of x where the slope is zero at the abline pictured below:
[image]

Is there a straightforward way to do this in RStudio? I'm having trouble with trying to figure out what the natural cubic spline formula would be and haven't had experience with derivatives since college. If it's helpful, here is the summary output:

[image]

[image]

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, one could simply differentiate the spline and solve for where the derivative is 0 (even if that solution requires some sort of root finding procedure).  Alternatively, you could just use a bisection method with predictions from the spline.

More practically, you can evaluate the spline over a fine grid to approximate the derivative using finite differences.  Here is an example

```r
library(splines)

set.seed(0)
# Simulate data
n <- 1000
x <- runif(n, min=0, max = 1)

# We already know the derivative is 0 at x=0.5
y <- sin(pi*x) + rnorm(n, 0, 0.3) 

plot(x, y)

knts <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8)
fit <- lm(y~ns(x, knots = knts, Boundary.knots = c(0.1, 0.9)))


## fine grid over which to evaluate the spline
h <- 1e-4
xx <- seq(0, 1, h)
yy <- predict(fit, newdata = list(x=xx))

lines(xx, yy, col='red', lwd=3)
```

[image]

```r
est_yprime <- diff(yy)/h

# Find the x which produces the smallest absolute yprime
x_min <- xx[order(abs(est_yprime))[1]]

# Close enough, and hovers around the right answer when you run it
# With different seeds
x_min
#> [1] 0.4611
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just piggybacking off the previous answer, there actually is a package in R designed to yield derivatives of natural splines, and you can pretty quickly obtain the derivatives of the fitted spline and then use a root finding package.

```
require(splines2)
require(rootSolve)

set.seed(1234)

n = 1000
x = rnorm(n);
basis = model.matrix(~naturalSpline(x,df=6,
                                    Boundary.knots = c(-4,4),
                                    knots = quantile(x,probs = seq(0.1,0.9,length.out=6))))
beta = rnorm(8,sd=3)

y = basis%*%beta + rnorm(n)
fit <- lm(y~-1+basis)

xeval = seq(min(x),max(x),0.01)
derivBasis = model.matrix(~-1+naturalSpline(xeval,
                                            Boundary.knots = c(-4,4),
                                            knots = quantile(x,probs = seq(0.1,0.9,length.out=6)),
                                            derivs = 1))
derivs = derivBasis%*%coef(fit)[-1]

deriv_func <- function(xpoint){
  naturalSpline(xpoint,
                Boundary.knots = c(-4,4),
                knots = quantile(x,probs = seq(0.1,0.9,length.out=6)),
                derivs = 1)%*%coef(fit)[-1]
}

zeroes = uniroot.all(deriv_func,interval = range(x))

plot(x,y,xlab='X',ylab='Y');abline(v=zeroes,lty=2)
lines(sort(x),fit$fitted.values[order(x)],col='red',lwd=5)
plot(xeval,derivs,xlab='X',ylab="df(X)/dx");abline(h=0);abline(v=zeroes,lty=2)
```

[image: ObsFit]
[image: FittedDeriv]